# Logic App Using Filter Query in Get Entities Action

Tags: odata, azure-table-storage, azure-logic-apps

I am new to logic app and try to build and logic app to check the records in Azure table. The PartitionKey is a string type of DateTime.utcNow().Ticks. I want to write a filter query to filter the records whose PartitionKey is less than or equals to current DateTime. My effort is shown in the screenshot:

[image]

It keeps telling me the expression is invalid. Can anyone give me some hints to write the correct query for my purpose? Many thanks. I am not sure why this expression is invalid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for George's hint, I just need to add single quote rather than using the `string()`. This will help me convert the ticks value to string so that I can compare it with the PartitionKey field.
[image]

In this way, it performs the same as this table query for me:

```
string currentDateTime = DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks.ToString();
TableQuery<EmailTableEntity> rangeQuery =
                                new TableQuery<EmailTableEntity>()
                                .Where(TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition
                                ("PartitionKey", QueryComparisons.LessThanOrEqual, currentDateTime));
```

Comment: How did you achieve this? I guess PartitionKey would be String type so we cannot compare String with DateTime ..

Comment: @Sachin As the query is shown, DateTime is converted to ticks.toString(), so it is comparing string with string

Answer (score 3):

Firstly your filter query expression, the format should be `Timestamp le datetime'2019-03-18T06:07Z'`.

Second the expression doesn't need the `ticks` function, if use it the query expression will be like the below pic hows.

[image]

So actually the right query expression should be `Timestamp le datetime '@{utcNow()}'`, if you get the warning, go the code view mode change the expression and don't forget the single quote.

[image]

[image]

And here is my test result, hope this could help you, if you still have other problem please feel free to let me know.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! This gives me some inspiration. But let me clarify my question. I store some specific date's ticks value in my PartitionKey, I hope to compare the ticks value with the current time's ticks value. Thank you.

Comment: I feel like as long as I add the single quote it will work?

Comment: No, without quote won't warn you with this prompt

Comment: And if this could help you, you could accept it as the answer.